# Непонятный абзац в книге

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования

В книге "PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования" (4-e издание), на 154-й странице есть следующий абзац:

> Нежесткая связь и высокая связность не являются автоматическими
>   признаками в контексте класса. В конце концов, мы можем включить целый
>   пример процедурного кода в один "неправильный" класс. Как же нам
>   достичь необходимого баланса в коде? Обычно я начинаю с рассмотрения
>   классов, которые должны присутствовать в моей системе.

Что здесь значит "не являются автоматическими признаками в контексте класса?
И о каком балансе речь?

Comment: Вероятнее всего ответ скрыт в предыдущих абзацах.

Comment: В предыдущих абзацах говорится о преимуществах нежёсткой связи и высокой связности.

Answer (score 1):

Мастер слова имел ввиду, что используя такие абстракции ООП как класс, вы не получаете качественный код автоматически. А в предложении о балансе речь о балансе между достоинствами и недостатками наличия состояния.

Главный недостаток процедурного программирования в том, что в нём очень много состояния. Вы выполняете процедуру и ожидаете, что состояние изменится (глобальные переменные поменяли значения, в stdout вывелся какой-то текст, в бд обновились ячейки таблиц). Концепция ООП предлагает изолировать состояние внутри объекта, однако и таким состоянием можно злоупотребить (например раскрывая его через геттеры). Но отказавшись от состояния вовсе, вы окажетесь в мире функционального программирования, которое часто отпугивает новичков своей чистотой.

Рассуждая о балансе, автор как бы спрашивает нас: "Так как же писать гибкий и в то же время понятный и легкоподдерживаемый код?".

Comment: Опять пьёшь без меня? Приходи в субботу, пойдём на ледянках с горы кататься!

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, тут имеется в виду правильный дизайн. "Нежесткая связь и высокая связность не являются автоматическими признаками хорошего дизайна".